# Holomorphic functions on upper half plane having same value on the Real axis

Tags: complex-analysis

$f, g$ are complex functions that are holomorphic on open upper half plane and continuous on closed upper half plane. 
Prove;
If $f$ and $g$ take the same values on a real open interval $(a,b)$ then they take the same values on the whole real axis.

I have a hunch that using holomorphicity we can use power series representations and using continuity we can expand on the boundary, the real axis. But, I am not sure as how to approach the problem.

I suggested using *identity theorem* and my instructor said we did not cover it in the class and instead suggested this theorem from our textbook:

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function in a region $Ω$ that vanishes on a sequence of distinct points with a limit point in $Ω$. Then $f$ is identically $0$.

However, I fail to see how I can use continuity and comment on the boundary as neither is mentioned in this theorem.

In the original text of the problem the restriction to the real axis was called an *upper limit function* which I omitted, I do not know if that helps. I am not sure if "upper limit function" is the precise terminology in English either, the original text is in another language.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know what holomorphic and continuous mean? Without knowing what you know it is difficult to give a useful reply. If you are simply seeking someone to do your work for you then this question will probably be quickly closed.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post.

Comment: $f-g$ is zero on $(a,b)$ so by Schwarz reflection $f-g$ extends to a part of the lower half-plane so it is holomorphic on a small open set containing $(a,b)$; by the identity theorem it follows that $f=g$ everywhere since $f=g$ on $(a,b)$

Comment: Thanks @Conrad. I came accross identity theorem in my own research as well. However my instructor said we did not cover identity theorem and instead suggested a theorem in our textbook, I am including it in the original post now.

Comment: These results are same (identity theorem means precisely that if two holomorphic functions coincide on a set with a limit point, they are equal as $f-g$ is zero there) - the point is to make $(a,b)$ which is original on the boundary to be interior and for that you need an extension theorem and Schwartz reflection is just that

Comment: @Conrad then I would have shown that f-g is 0 on the entire strip a<Re(z)<b. My concern is to expand on the real axis. Am I misreading you? How can I know that f-g takes real values on the entire ${R}$, so that I can apply Schwars reflection on the whole function?

Comment: If k is continuous on closed upper half plane and $h \colon z \mapsto \overline{k(\bar{z})}$. Do I know h is continuous on closed lower half plane?